# Batch Requests Bearer Token

Tags: c#, .net, bearer-token

After setting up support for batch requests in my .net framework web app. Each of the individual requests return forbidden, even when I copy my bearer token to each of the individual requests.
My integration test for the my batch support is bellow - my ServerHelper code adds the bearer token the requests.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public async Task BatchRequestTest()
{
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, ServerHelper.HttpClient.BaseAddress + "values/22");

    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await ServerHelper.GetAccessToken());

    var getMetricsRequest = new HttpMessageContent(requestMessage);
    var getTransactionsRequest1 = new HttpMessageContent(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, ServerHelper.HttpClient.BaseAddress + "values/23"));
    var failingRequest = new HttpMessageContent(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, ServerHelper.HttpClient.BaseAddress + "values/77"));
    MultipartContent content = new MultipartContent("mixed", "batch_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    content.Add(getMetricsRequest);
    content.Add(getTransactionsRequest1);
    content.Add(failingRequest);


    HttpRequestMessage batchRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, ServerHelper.HttpClient.BaseAddress + "batch")
    {
        Content = content
    };

    var response = await ServerHelper.HttpClient.SendAsync(batchRequest);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);//assert true


    var responseContents = await response.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

    var get1 = await responseContents.Contents[0].ReadAsHttpResponseMessageAsync();
    var get2 = await responseContents.Contents[1].ReadAsHttpResponseMessageAsync();
    var get3 = await responseContents.Contents[2].ReadAsHttpResponseMessageAsync();


    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, get1.StatusCode);//assert fail
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, get2.StatusCode);//assert fail
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, get3.StatusCode);
}
```

Part of my configuration responsible for adding batch support:

```cs
var server = new HttpServer(httpConfiguration);

appBuilder.UseWebApi(server);

httpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpBatchRoute(
    routeName: "batch",
    routeTemplate: "batch",
    batchHandler: new DefaultHttpBatchHandler(server)
    {
        ExecutionOrder = BatchExecutionOrder.NonSequential
    }
);
```

Do I need to add something to my pipeline?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this? I am having the same issue and need to set the bearer token on my batch requests.

Answer (score 0):

Notice you added the Authorization header to another local variable called `requestMessage`. Try adding the authorization header to your `batchRequest` variable and/or create the other `HttpMessageContent` instances with `requestMessage` as a constructor argument.

Comment: I wasn't clear when I pasted my code. But the Serverhelper adds the Authorisation Header to the batch request. That step you mentioned was and experiement to check if  adding the bearer token to one of the _inner_ requests. I wouldn't have the unauthorised issue.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this issue today, so thought I would post a solution in case anyone else wonders about this. You can crete a custom batch handler by extending DefaultHttpBatchHandler. Within this you can then set authorization headers on child requests.

```
public class AuthorizationBatchHandler : DefaultHttpBatchHandler
{
    public AuthorizationBatchHandler(HttpServer httpServer) : base(httpServer)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<IList<HttpRequestMessage>> ParseBatchRequestsAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var requests = await base.ParseBatchRequestsAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        foreach (var childRequest in requests)
        {
            childRequest.Headers.Authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;
        }
        return requests;
    }
}
```

You then wire it up in your startup method as follows:

```
        httpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpBatchRoute(
            routeName: "batch",
            routeTemplate: "batch",
            batchHandler: new AuthorizationBatchHandler(server));
```

That's all there is to do.